# Emacs company-mode completion not working

Tags: macos, emacs

I just began using emacs a few days ago and I've been having trouble setting up company-mode. I installed company-mode using package-install and added the following in my .emacs  file :-

```
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

Yet, when I go over to haskell-mode, company-mode completion doesn't pop up at all (likewise with racket-mode) when I wait for a few seconds on a keyword. Could I have installed something that could have been messing up or conflicting with company-mode? 
Also, when I try to invoke company-complete manually, it just says "no completion found".

Edit: Tried out auto-complete as an alternative and code completion does not work when I press tab, but when i invoke auto-complete on a word, it works.

Edit2: got auto-complete to work. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjOT1.png 
It looks like flyspell-mode was conflicting with auto-complete. But, No luck with getting company mode to work. 
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Since you installed via `package.el`, there's no need for `(require 'company)`.  Also, I don't see any need to use `after-init-hook` rather than a plain `(global-company-mode 1)`.  Of course, that doesn't make any difference to your problem.  If you go to `*scratch*` and type `(doli` do you get some completion inserted by company (you should)?  If so, maybe the problem is simply that there is no support for Haskell/Racket completion.

Comment: Oh, I do get completion this time around. Looks like so https://imgur.com/Hr4yNTV
Is this how it's supposed to look ?

Comment: Also, I got auto-complete to work with haskell and racket-mode, but I can't have flyspell minor-mode on while using auto-complete-mode 
Is there any workaround for this? I'd like to use flyspell-prog-mode to find out any misspellings in my comments. Well, I can live without it tbh, but I'd like to use it.

Comment: Try `ac-flyspell-workaround`.

Comment: I guess the issue with Haskell/Racket and Company is that Company does not find any source of completions.  Ideally, the source of completions should be provided by the major mode, so it's available to the standard `completion-at-point` <key>M-TAB</key> completion as well as to Company and probably a few others.  If not, you may find some company-haskell and/or company-racket package somewhere providing that source of completions.  I suggest you file a bug report with the haskell mode and racket mode asking they add an appropriate `completion-at-point-function`.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the info. I looked up and found a package to add a backend to company to work with haskell. As for racket-mode, there is no support for company as of yet (But hey, I can use auto-complete with both racket/haskell mode.)

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got completion to work for `company-mode` in haskell without much hassle. 
All I had to do was add company backends to my .emacs :-

```
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev-code) 
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-yasnippet)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-files)
```

And get the package `intero` which adds `company-mode` support for haskell. Like so :-

```
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'intero-mode))
```

As for `racket-mode`, I add this in my .emacs :-

```
  (defun my-racket-mode-hook () 
    (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
         '((company-capf company-dabbrev-code)))
    (company-quickhelp-mode 0))
  (add-hook 'racket-mode-hook 'my-racket-mode-hook)
  (add-hook 'racket-mode-hook 'company-mode)
  (add-hook 'racket-repl-mode-hook 'my-racket-mode-hook)
  (add-hook 'racket-repl-mode-hook 'company-mode)
```